# Is it possible to create a output cell without generating a cell tag from the input cell

Tags: front-end

I give a CellTag to my Input Cell, but the output cell would also inherit the CellTag.

Is it possible to control not inherit the CellTag?

Sometimes I need the output cell with the CellTag, but sometimes I don't need...

---

#### Application

I found another method is use another tags to do the same thing.

I want to select some cells with some tags, cells with "Ignore" tag will be omitted, only Input Style Cells with"Ignore1" tag will be omitted, Output Style Cells with "Ignore1" tag will be kept.

for example, I select the cells without "Ignore" and "Ignore1" tags.

```
Select[NotebookRead@Cells[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
FreeQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore"]&&FreeQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore1"] &]
```

but this omit the output cells with "Ignore1", how to include these output cells?

This is my sub question, if the original question is unsolvable.

---

so the condition could be.

```
condition=FreeQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore"] && (#[[2]] === "Output" && 
MemberQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore1"]) &
```

---

#### One method

We've add a `CellTags->"Ignore"` in the Input cell, just add a new CellTag, the the Output cell by CellPrint will tagged by new tag `Hello`   !

```
CellPrint@Cell["Test",CellTags->"Hello"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main question**

I don't think this is possible. You can however delete such `CellTags` programmatically, using this

```
SetOptions[#, CellTags -> {}] & /@ 
 Cells[CellTags -> "tag", CellStyle -> "Output"]
```

**Sub question**

How about something like this

```
Complement[Cells[], Cells[CellTags -> "Ignore"], 
 Cells[CellTags -> "Ignore1", CellStyle -> "Input"]]
```

Comment: yes, the problem is some "Output" style cells need "tag", some doesn't.

Comment: @HyperGroups ah that is more specific and harder than I thought.

Comment: I found another method to deal with this situation is Just add another `tag1` to the Input Cell.

Comment: for example, I select the cells without "Ignore" and "Ignore1" tags.

`Select[NotebookRead@Cells[EvaluationNotebook[]], FreeQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore"]&&FreeQ[#, CellTags -> "Ignore1"] &]`, but this omit the output cells with "Ignore1", how to include these output cells.

Comment: I've modified my question include a real application. I think you can develop your answer to make my question and your answer more applicable.

Comment: `CellPrint@Cell["Test",CellTags->"Hello"]`
I found just add a new tag, will delete the Input Cell's tag.